# Animate coupled ODEs in python with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, spyder, ode

I am trying to animate a set of 5 coupled ODEs with matplotlib depicting flow change in time.

My project is to determine how is pollutant advancing through the Great Lakes depending on the starting lake and different flow speeds. For this I have 5 ODEs. So far I've managed to make a model and get results for different flows and different starting positions. I'm currently stuck on animating those results. I made some animations but they are not working properly.

!https://i.stack.imgur.com/FK2Kp.jpg

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as anim

""" Volume [m^3] """
V1 = 12004e9        # Superior
V2 = 3550e9         # Huron
V3 = 4860e9         # Michigan
V4 = 499e9          # Erie
V5 = 1656e9         # Ontario

""" Flows [m^3/s] """
r1 = 2.2e3*3.154e7     #->Superior
r2 = 1.6e3*3.154e7     #->Huron
r3 = 1.5e3*3.154e7     #->Michigan
r4 = 0.7e3*3.154e7     #->Erie
r5 = 1.1e3*3.154e7     #->Ontario
r6 = 5.3e3*3.154e7     #Huron->Erie
r7 = 6e3*3.154e7       #Erie->Ontario
r8 = 7.1e3*3.154e7     #Ontario->

r = np.array([r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7,r8])

""" Time """
t=18000
T = np.linspace(0,t,t+1)
""" Initial Condition"""
x10 = 0.001*V1
S0 = np.array([x10,0,0,0,0])
def Sup(S,T,R):
    dx1dt = -R[0]/V1*S[0]
    dx2dt = R[0]/V1*S[0] + R[2]/V3*S[2] - R[5]/V2*S[1]
    dx3dt = -R[2]/V3*S[2]
    dx4dt = R[5]/V2*S[1] - R[6]/V4*S[3]
    dx5dt = R[6]/V4*S[3] - R[7]/V5*S[4]
    return np.array([dx1dt, dx2dt, dx3dt, dx4dt, dx5dt])

R = r   #there are multiple flow variants used later in the code
S1 = odeint(Sup,S0,T,args=(R,))
SSuperior = S1[:,0]
SHuron = S1[:,1]
SMichigan = S1[:,2]
SErie = S1[:,3]
SOntario = S1[:,4]

""" Animation"""
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim = (-50, 8500))
line, = ax.plot([], [], animated = True, lw = 2)
def init():
    line.set_data([],[])
    ax.set_xlim(T.min(),T.max())
    ax.set_ylim(SOntario.min(), SOntario.max())
    return line,
def animate(i):
    line.set_data(T,SOntario[i])
    return line,
anim = anim.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames = 500, init_func = init, blit=True )
```

My first expected animation was just to animate the plotting, but all I can get is a horizontal line moving up and down. While this is partially right it is not the expected animation

Comment: What if you did `line.set_data(T[i:i+100],SOntario[i:i+100])`?

Comment: I tried and it is working almost perfect. Currently it is making a finite length line and moving it along the path. Modifying it to `line.set_data(T[0:i+100],SOntario[0:i+100])` did the trick. Now all I need to do is to figure out the best speed for ploting. Thanks :D